# Checkbox activity in action bar to change the color of textView in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, colors, textview

On my welcome page, there is an action bar with preferences as its only option. When clicked, it takes the user to another activity with three options that all have checkboxes. When one or two of the checkboxes are pressed, when the user goes back to the welcome page, the color of the textView should change as chosen. I believe I have coded the checkboxes properly, but I am unable to make the changes to reflect on the TextView. What can I do to solve that?

This is my Welcome class,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.graphics.Color;


public class Welcome extends Activity {

TextView textView;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String NAME="UserName";
String defaultName = "";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences mypreferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    textView.setText("Welcome," + sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, defaultName));
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(NAME, sharedPreferences.getString(NAME,defaultName));
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    boolean checkBox;
    boolean checkBox2;
    boolean checkBox3;
    mypreferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    checkBox = mypreferences.getBoolean("checkBox", false);
    checkBox2 = mypreferences.getBoolean("checkBox2", false);
    checkBox3 = mypreferences.getBoolean("checkBox3", false);

    if (checkBox && !checkBox2 && !checkBox3) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (!checkBox && checkBox2 && !checkBox3) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (!checkBox && !checkBox2 && checkBox3) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (checkBox && checkBox2 && !checkBox3) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (checkBox && !checkBox2 && checkBox3) {
        textView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    }



}

    @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, MainActivity.class));
    return;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_preferences){
        startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this,Preferences.class));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and this is my preferences page which has the code for all the checkboxes.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Preferences extends Activity {

CheckBox checkBox;
CheckBox checkBox2;
CheckBox checkBox3;
TextView textView;
SharedPreferences mypreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor myeditor;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.preferences);
    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    checkBox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

    mypreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    myeditor= mypreferences.edit();

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                myeditor.putBoolean("checkBox", true);
            } else {
                myeditor.putBoolean("checkBox", false);
            }
            myeditor.apply();
        }
    });
    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                myeditor.putBoolean("checkBox2", true);
            } else {
                myeditor.putBoolean("checkBox2", false);
            }
            myeditor.apply();

        }
    });
    checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                myeditor.putBoolean("checkBox3", true);
            } else {
                myeditor.putBoolean("checkBox3", false);
            }
            myeditor.apply();
        }
    });

}
}
```

I need the checkboxes in the preferences page to change the textView on the welcome page.
Please help!

Welcome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Red Option"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is red option"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Green Option"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is green option"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Blue Option"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is blue option"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you should do it. Save your check boxes values in `SharedPreferences`, then use these values to set your text view color.

**Welcome.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

    TextView textView;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public static final String NAME = "UserName";
    String defaultName = "";
    SharedPreferences myPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        textView.setText("Welcome," + sharedPreferences.getString(NAME, defaultName));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        boolean checkBox1Value = myPreferences.getBoolean("checkBox1", false);
        boolean checkBox2Value = myPreferences.getBoolean("checkBox2", false);
        boolean checkBox3Value = myPreferences.getBoolean("checkBox3", false);

        //Be ware here that there are other conditions that are not mentioned like for
        //example "checkBox1Value && checkBox2Value && checkBox3Value" and 3 other conditions
        //too (Total 4 unmentioned). If any conditions are not mentioned here and you set these
        //unmentioned conditions from your preferences, your TextView color will not change. So
        //you should also mention these 4 conditions.
        if (checkBox1Value && !checkBox2Value && !checkBox3Value) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (!checkBox1Value && checkBox2Value && !checkBox3Value) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (!checkBox1Value && !checkBox2Value && checkBox3Value) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (checkBox1Value && checkBox2Value && !checkBox3Value) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (checkBox1Value && !checkBox2Value && checkBox3Value) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_preferences){
            startActivity(new Intent(Welcome.this, Preferences.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Preferences.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Preferences extends Activity {

    CheckBox checkBox1;
    CheckBox checkBox2;
    CheckBox checkBox3;
    SharedPreferences myPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

        checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);

        myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        myEditor = myPreferences.edit();

        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    myEditor.putBoolean("checkBox1", true);
                } else {
                    myEditor.putBoolean("checkBox1", false);
                }
                myEditor.apply();
            }
        });

        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    myEditor.putBoolean("checkBox2", true);
                } else {
                    myEditor.putBoolean("checkBox2", false);
                }
                myEditor.apply();
            }
        });

        checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    myEditor.putBoolean("checkBox3", true);
                } else {
                    myEditor.putBoolean("checkBox3", false);
                }
                myEditor.apply();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        boolean checkBox1Value = myPreferences.getBoolean("checkBox1", false);
        boolean checkBox2Value = myPreferences.getBoolean("checkBox2", false);
        boolean checkBox3Value = myPreferences.getBoolean("checkBox3", false);

        checkBox1.setChecked(checkBox1Value);
        checkBox2.setChecked(checkBox2Value);
        checkBox3.setChecked(checkBox3Value);
    }
}
```

**welcome.xml**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Red Option"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is red option"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Green Option"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is green option"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minHeight="80dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minWidth="200dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Blue Option"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="This is blue option"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:checked="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have fixed all your code. The most important thing you need to do now is mentioning what to do when the other 4 unmentioned conditions are set as I have commented in the activity above.

Comment: it does not change the color :/

Comment: @AriaMontgomery Can you post your both layout xmls please to let me check?

Comment: I have made a very silly mistake. I wrote a wrong setContentView() in your Welcome.java. Check my updated answer. :)

Comment: still didn't work. do you think i would need to add any special code, since the xml with the checkboxes are under an option from the action bar. The codes look ok to me, but this is my first time working with action bar so I don't know if there is anything special i'd have to code in

Comment: Probably best to use a PreferenceActivity for preferences IMO

Comment: @AriaMontgomery How come? It worked for me. Did you make sure you wrote correct class names with their correct layouts in the code? Also did you declare them in the AppManifest.xml?

Comment: yes i did all of that :( i will try and copy all of your code and replace mine with yours just in case I'm missing anything and then let you know if it works

Comment: @HusseinElFeky I have replaced the code i have in the question with the one i have in my android studio. could you please try to run mine and see what the problem is, please? thank you

Comment: @Aria Check my updated answer. Copy it all even the xmls.

Comment: @Aria No problem. Glad it worked! Please don't forget to vote my answer up as well. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You made a simple mistake which is that you forget to set textView to a real textView 
If you checked the code you will find that you defined checkBox,checkBox2 and checkBox 3 and gave there ids while you forget to give the textView that you want to change it's color an Id

Comment: i did that, but the color still did not change